# How to store field preset in database?

Tags: mysql

I have to show huge table to the user, and I need to allow user to select which fields he wants to see.

The question is: what is the best way to store those fields in the database? The only idea I've got so far is to crate a table like this:

[image]

and set those fields to `0` or `1`, but it seems a bad idea to me.

What's the beast approach?

Comment: I think entity-attribute-value is more suitable, also column type BIT is better than tinyint (tinyint accept value others than 0,1), For bit, only 0 or 1.

Comment: @ajreal I cant figure out how to use EAV here, could you propose some example or something? Thanks for `BIT`, anyway :)

Comment: @ajreal There is no datatype bit in mysql, just boolean and that is actually a synonym for tinyint(1) <- yes, it's in the manual.

Comment: Table will contain `user_id, field_name, enabled` only pick those records which are enabled against a given `user_id`. If `Order` of fields is customisable, use another column `disp_order`.

Comment: @SparKot I guess you can make it an answer, so that I can accept it - this works well.

Comment: @tombom there is bit type - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-type.html

Comment: @ajreal Okay, didn't think of using it with BIT(1), yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the table be :
`(user_id, field_name, enabled)`

**or** if display order is needed too
`(user_id, field_name, disp_order, enabled)`

Pick those records which are `enabled` against a given `user_id` (sorted by `disp_order` if needed).